# Google's Strict CSP 3, style-src?

Tags: content-security-policy

Engineers at Google have developed and recommend using a strict CSP: https://csp.withgoogle.com/docs/strict-csp.html

The goal being to only allow scripts which have a nonce. There is no style-src directive in their CSP, so in our app I am able to load things like google fonts, external css sheets etc. *without* a nonce.

This seems like a lapse in their CSP, or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is that the newer 'strict-dynamic' setting they recommend is allowing the autoloading of some of your dependancies.

> The 'strict-dynamic' source expression aims to make Content Security
>   Policy simpler to deploy for existing applications who have a high
>   degree of confidence in the scripts they load directly, but low
>   confidence in their ability to provide a reasonable list of resources
>   to load up front.
>
> It allows scripts which are given access to
>   the page via nonces or hashes to bring in their dependencies without
>   adding them explicitly to the page’s policy.

ref: https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#strict-dynamic-usage